# Change the color of error bars when using Around in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I wanted to use Around to plot values with uncertainties in ListPlot. But when I used PlotStyle to change the color, it only changes the color of the dots but not the error bars; for example

```
ListPlot[{Around[1, 0.1]}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

How can I also change the color of the error bars?

Comment: This is a version-specific problem. The error bar is `Red` in v12.0 and v12.2 on my Mac; however, in v12.1.1 I need to use `ListPlot[{Around[1, 0.1]}, PlotStyle -> Red] /. RGBColor[__] :> Red`

Comment: See also `IntervalMarkersStyle`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With v12.0 or v12.2 the color of the error bars match the `PlotStyle`; however, with v12.1.1

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

ListPlot[{
  {{1, Around[1, 0.1]}, {3, Around[2, 0.1]}},
  {{2, Around[2, 0.1]}, {4, Around[1.5, 0.1]}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Darker@Green},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

A workaround is to replace each `RGBColor` with the associated `PlotStyle`

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ListPlot[
    {{1, Around[1, 0.1]}, {3, Around[2, 0.1]}}, PlotStyle -> Red] /. 
   RGBColor[__] :> Red,
  ListPlot[
    {{2, Around[2, 0.1]}, {4, Around[1.5, 0.1]}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Darker@Green] /. RGBColor[__] :> Darker@Green,
  PlotRange -> All],
 PointLegend[{Red, Darker@Green}, Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, Thanks a lot for your comment and your answer! Indeed I was using 12.1.1 and once I upgraded to 12.2.0 it works.